# How to make a listenener relation not recursiv

Tags: java, swing, awt

I broke down my code to the base of my theoretical problem

```
public class main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {    
        new Object1().a();
    }
}

public class Object1 {

    private static Object2 object2;

    public Object1() {

    }

    public void a(){

        object2 = new Object2(this);
        object2.setVisible(true);
        System.out.println("new object2 created");

    }

    public void b(){

        object2 = null;
        System.out.println("set object2 to null");
        a();

    }
}

/**
 *
 *Class creates JFrame with a button.
 *the button has an event listener which calls method b form object1
 *
 */

public class Object2 extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    private JButton jButton1;
    private Object1 object1;

    public Object2(Object1 ob1) {

        super();
        this.object1 = ob1;
        initGUI();

    }

    private void initGUI() {
        try {
            setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
            {
                jButton1 = new JButton();
                getContentPane().add(jButton1, BorderLayout.CENTER);
                jButton1.setText("click me");
                jButton1.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(311, 143));
                jButton1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {

                        jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
                    }
                });
            }
            pack();
            this.setSize(150, 125);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {

        System.out.println("button clicked");

        object1.b();

    }
```

the call of my jFrame is most likely a recursion, the consequence is that setting the Frame null won't do anything ...
the Frame is still visible and works without throwing a NullPointerException.
But thats not the center of the problem.

The Question is :
How can I write an equivalent code to this without a recursion?

Comment: If I understand this correctly: You want to destroy the current frame and create & show a new one, right? If yes, why aren't you calling `object2.dispose();`? - That would work.

Answer (score 0):

is `JFrame` not centered? is that the problem. or you have some design issues. ?

```
object2.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
```

it will center the `JFrame`

otherwise if design problem ,use a setter for any one of those.. something like

```
public class Object2 extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    private JButton jButton1;
    private Object1 object1;

    public Object2(Object1 ob1) {

        super();
        initGUI();

    }

    public void setObject1(Object1 object1){
        this.object1 = object1;
    }

........
```

call the setter after the object creation of object2 in `Object1`

Comment: the problem is not a design issue or something like this, the problem is, if you press the button, it follows a recursive call of object1 and object2 will not be destroyed. instead  i have two equivalent working object2's

Comment: **object2 = null**. what you are trying to do? you mean close the JFrame?

Comment: then do object2.setVisible(false) or object2.dispose();

Comment: i would like to free the object2 from RAM after pressing the button, but set to null dont work because its recursive and object2 is still part of the stack